Getting Promo Code IAP (not offer code) on the SKPaymentQueue using SwiftyStoreKit
I'm trying to get Promo Codes Redeemed from the app store to work inside my iOS app. Please note that these are different from offer codes - which are for subscriptions and they work with presenting an UI.
I'm using SwiftyStoreKit and in applicationDidFinishLaunching I've put their code:
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // see notes below for the meaning of Atomic / Non-Atomic
    SwiftyStoreKit.completeTransactions(atomically: true) { purchases in
        for purchase in purchases {
            switch purchase.transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased, .restored:
                if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                    // Deliver content from server, then:
                    SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
                }
                // Unlock content
            case .failed, .purchasing, .deferred:
                break // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}

and handle the delivering functionality of the IAP before calling :
SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
But there seems there is no call to the SwiftyStoreKit.completeTransactions callback.
Isn't this the method that should get called to make redeeming promo codes work ?
